# Is runtime o(logn) or o(n)?

Tags: algorithm

I'm somewhat confused by this problem. It seems that with each step, the size of the problem is reduced by a half, which suggests O(logn). But if you really think about it, the number of interations is just the geometric series 2 + 4 + 8 + ... less than n, which suggests O(n). Can some one please offer their insights?

```
for (int i=1; i < n; i=2i)
    for (int j=i; j < n; j++)
        // do something
```

Comment: Try it! That's generally a good way to check your intuition, although it's occasionally misleading.

Comment: Also, note: `j` starts at `i` and ends at `n`. How much work does that inner loop do, then?

Comment: Your comment about the geometric progression isn't right. It would be if j went from 1 to i.

Comment: Your title uses little-o but your question text uses big-O...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A good way to go about this is to calculate the complexity of the inner and outer loops separately. Once you do that, you can just calculate the product of the two to get the total complexity.

You can also think of this in terms of how many steps will be required in each loop, which serves as a good sanity check of the method. By the same logic as before, it's clear to see that since `i` grows geometrically, the number of iterations in that loop that will actually occur is going to be the inverse of that, or `O(log n)`.

If you then want to see how many inner loops will run for a given `n`, it's pretty clear that, since you have a single step per `n`, the inner loop will be linear for a given result of the outer loop. This gives a complexity of `O(n)`

This method returns a result of `O(n log n)`

Comment: the complexity of the outer loop should be O(log(n)) no, since we only need log(n) steps to exceed n?

Comment: @codeMonkey17 That calculation of the outer loop is simply calculating how many inner loops need to run. Depending on exactly how you structure your definitions, you could switch the complexity of the inner and outer loops, but I thought this way was more intuitive.

Comment: @codeMonkey17 I'll update the answer to add in the alternate explanation.

Comment: ok, does O(n) * O(log n) evaluate to O(n log n)? what is the logic?

Comment: @ Slater Tyranus Also, would it make sense to calculate a tight bound in this case? Can we show that the run time is omega(c * nlogn)?

Comment: @codeMonkey17 Because you're effectively doing one complexity's worth of the inner loop per outer loop. Like, if I did 5 inner loops per outer loop and did 4 outer loops I would do 20 loops total. Same logic applies. Whether or not it makes sense is completely dependent on your application. Unless you have to know this to some great accuracy I don't think it makes sense to bother, though it is certainly possible.

Comment: Wow... someone went through and downvoted every single answer without posting a single comment about it.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I generally disagree with the analysis you describe above. That thought process suffices for a big-Oh bound but not for a Theta bound (which is often what people mean when they say big-Oh). For instance suppose that he changed the second loop to be `j = 0; j < i; j++` then your analysis would still yield `O(n log n)` which is true... but it wouldn't be tight. In particular, it'd be `Theta(n) => O(n)`

Comment: @roliu I answered the question presented, but the analysis above certainly does extend to a Theta bound. I'm sorry if the analysis above wasn't clear to you, but the tight bound would NOT be `Theta(n)`. The tight bound would only be `Theta(n)` if it were: `j=i/2; j < i; j++`, in which case my method would reveal so. Using Simply realizing that there is an amount of repetition proportional to `n` shows that the tight bound of that problem couldn't possibly be `Theta(n)`.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus My comment does not say that the above algorithm has a `Theta(n)` bound, please reread it (in fact, you can look at my answer on this page to see my proof for the `Theta(nlogn)` bound). Can you please explain how the logic presented above yields the `Theta(n)` bound for the _other_ case where the inner loop is `j = 0; j < i; j++` because... that algorithm indeed has a `Theta(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be exactly `sum(sum(1, j = (2^i)..n), i = 1..log(n)) = nlog(n) - 2n + log(n) + 2 = O(n log n)`

Comment: hmm, I understand how you got sum(sum(1, j = (2^i)..n), i = 1..log(n)), but I not sure I follow how you got the right side of the equation :/

Answer (score 0):

the complexity is O(n log n)

at first for more clearance for example:
when n is 4 the outer loop iterates 2 times
when n is 64 the ouret loop iterates 6 times
so the outer loop iterates log2(n) times.

the solution:
at first iteration of the outer loop the "do somethings" statement is running n times
at second iteration of the outer loop the "do somethings" statement is running n-2 times
at last iteration of the outer loop the "do somethings" statement is running n-log2(n) times

so for total execution of the program, the "do somethings" statement is running n+n-2+n-4+...+n-log2(n) times.
it is equal to n*log2(n)-(1+2+4+8+...+log2(n)) = n*log2(n)-(2n-1) times.
so the complexity is o(n log n)

Comment: The claim and proof are both wrong. It doesn't "run `n/2` times" on the second iteration, it runs `n - 2` times. You'll see if you break up the summation that it's actually `Theta(nlogn) - Theta(n) = Theta(nlogn)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `do something` is `Theta(1)` then the algorithm should be `Theta(nlog(n))` as U2EF1 suggests.

Here's an explanation of how you might find the closed formula for the double summation:

```
Sum p in [1, logn] (Sum j in [2^p, n] 1) =
Sum p in [1, logn] (n - 2^p) =
nlogn - Sum p in [1, logn] (2^p) =
nlogn - Theta(n) =
Theta(nlogn)
```

In particular, you can evaluate the final summation using the [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series) for the first `n` terms in a geometric series. Or you can use a more limited variant which is something like "think of `n` as a binary number such as `1111` and notice that if you sum each of the powers `2^p` from `p = 1 to log(n)` then you've got `n` again".

A closed form suffices to prove the `Theta` bound, although you need to use other common lemmas in complexity analysis to show steps like `Theta(nlogn) - Theta(n) = Theta(nlogn)`.